# How to get the Width and Height of an UIComponent, after rotating that component in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am trying to get width and height of an UIComponent after rotation of that component by using

```
var width:Number = component.getLayoutBoundsWidth();
var height:Number = component.getLayoutBoundsHeight();
```

But it is returning the width and height same as before rotation of the UIComponent.

Anybody have an idea how to get the updated height and width of an UIComponent after rotation or how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getBounds()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds()) to get the display bounding box.